# Improving the reputation question in the faq

Tags: feature-request, reputation

I was looking at my reputation gains today and I noticed that for some posts I had a net gain of +65 reputation points.

The fact that the number was odd struck me as strange, since I had read in the faq that you would get +10 for an upvote and -2 for a downvote (and no matter how you add/substract/multiply two even numbers, you cannot obtain an odd number).

I looked at the post and noticed that I had gotten 5 up votes and the answer had been accepted, so I supposed that giving the accepted answer would net +15 points, however I do not understand why it is not on the FAQ or a page pointed to by the faq.

It does not seem to take much to add this.

Comment: You also get 2 points for accepting an answer to your question, and that isn't listed either.

Comment: Whoa.  Seems like a rather large oversight here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agreed. The rep cap bit is incorrect too.

Here's the current text:

> Here's how it works: if you post a
> good question or helpful answer, it
> will be voted up by your peers: you
> gain 10 reputation points. If you post
> something that's off topic or
> incorrect, it will be voted down: you
> lose 2 reputation points. You can earn
> up to 200 reputation per day, but no
> more. (Note that votes for any posts
> marked "community wiki" do not
> generate reputation.)

My suggested replacement:

> Here's how it works: if you post a
> good question or helpful answer, it
> will be voted up by your peers: you
> gain 10 reputation points. If you post
> something that's off topic or
> incorrect, it will be voted down: you
> lose 2 reputation points. If an answer is
> accepted by the person asking the question,
> you gain an extra 15 points - and the questioner
> gains 2 points for accepting the answer. You don't
> get anything for casting an upvote, but a downvote
> costs 1 point.
>
> If you earn
> 200 reputation in a day, only accepted answers
> (or "bounty" - see below) will give you any
> more reputation for the rest of that day.
> "Days" are measured from UTC midnight to UTC midnight.
>
> Note that votes for any posts
> marked "community wiki" do not
> generate reputation - although they can still
> earn you badges.

Comment: I used this in my FAQ (http://forceclose.com/faq) hope you don't mind!

Comment: That's fine by me.