# Clarification in FAQ regarding voting, reputation, and accepted answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, accepted-answer, faq-update-request

I think [the FAQ on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) is *slightly* confusing. To quote one line regarding reputation changes...

> answer is accepted  +15  (+2 to voter)

I interpret this to mean that the person who actually accepts the answer gets +2. It certainly doesn't mean that anyone who had voted on the accepted answer gets +2 (which would bring untold amounts of chaos). But the term "voter" implies some integration with the like-wise-named system, the voting system. On the same note, the act of "accepting" an answer isn't really voting at all. So does it actually mean the OP only gets the +2 if the OP voted on it before accepting it?

Admittedly, I don't even know if "accepter" is a real word at all, and it certainly sounds awkward on the tongue, but I think it might be nice to make the FAQ a bit more proper sounding.

...filing under 'feature-request' since I think that's appropriate for this...

**EDIT**

I did find the answer to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25169/improving-the-reputation-question-in-the-faq) which included a different verbiage. Probably from a time before land.

Also, in the current FAQ, it should be noted that the other 3 listed reputation changers all relate to voting directly, so it really is strongly implied by saying "voter" that this +2 is also related to voting.

Comment: Something like "original poster" or "question poster" would be accurate but equally awkward.

Comment: @ChrisF: "asker"? Not to be confused with any [city in Norway](http://www.google.com/search?q=define:asker).

Comment: @json - that would probably do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok updated to

> acceptor

for that line

Answer (score 3):

It means that the OP gets the +2 if he accepts an answer that it's not his own.

The FAQ should be reworded.

Answer (score 2):

Which FAQ are you referring to?

[This FAQ answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238) about reputation has the proper wording and is less confusing.

Comment: Useful link! To answer, though, I'm referring to the general FAQ that you find by clicking "faq" at the top right corner. I only know it is there specifically at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [Ether's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46750/clarification-in-faq-regarding-voting-reputation-and-accepted-answers/46753#46753). The two rep changes should be broken into two separate lines to make things more clear.

The use of the word "voter" comes from the fact that internally, accepting an answer is a vote. In fact, most of the actions on the site are "votes" -- [see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/anatomy-of-a-data-dump/2678#2678) for all the different kinds of votes if you're curious (I think that answer is slightly out of date, but it gets the point across).

Comment: ...huh, so voter is technically correct. I didn't know that. But semantically, it remains confusing nevertheless. Thanks!

Comment: @ccomet: Yep. It makes sense to an author of the system (or those privy to the internals), but not so much to a normal user.