# Is the wording in Stack Overflow FAQ correct? Is it confusing?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clarification in FAQ regarding voting, reputation, and accepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46750/clarification-in-faq-regarding-voting-reputation-and-accepted-answers)

The Stack Overflow [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) contains the section on Reputation listed below.

> To gain reputation, post good
>   questions and useful answers. Your
>   peers will vote on your posts, and
>   those votes will cause you to gain
>   (or, in rare cases, lose) reputation:
>
> - answer is voted up  +10
> - question is voted up  +5
> - answer is accepted +15  (+2 to voter)
> - post is voted down  -2  (-1 to voter)

Is the parenthesis next to point 3 a typo?  Does voter mean "person accepting the answer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment in parentheses is correct.  You get +15 if your answer is accepted, and you get +2 when *you accept* an answer.  I can't really say if it's confusing or not since I've been around awhile.

Comment: It seems [to be](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46750/clarification-in-faq-regarding-voting-reputation-and-accepted-answers/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it means person accepting the answer.