# Comment count incorrect after system auto-deletes "duplicate of" comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677060/programming-language-for-fast-calculations-with-big-integers) was just closed as a duplicate. The first comment was an auto-added "possible duplicate of..." comment, which was the ultimate reason the question was closed.

After the question was closed, the auto-added duplicate comment was removed as expected, and there are two comments remaining. However, there is still an "add / show 1 more comment" link which when clicked, shows no more comments and only the add comment box.

Comment: Seen this in a few other questions, too. [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47297/is-the-wording-in-stack-overflow-faq-correct-is-it-confusing-closed) is another recent example.

Comment: Aha, if this is [status-completed], then maybe [Not all comments shown, but no “show .. more comments”? (Or: auto-comments are not counted correctly?)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44538/not-all-comments-shown-but-no-show-more-comments-or-auto-comments-are-no) is [status-completed] as well?

Answer (score 2):

[An additional example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47289/merging-singular-and-plural-forms-of-tags-closed)

It looks like this is just a simple case of not updating the denormalized comment count after removing the duplicate link comment.