# "OpCode 'Votes' not defined" bug deleting a post for second time(while it was deleted)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, voting

I tried to delete a post for a second time but was met with the following dialog:

> This post has been deleted; deleted posts can't be voted on.

Why on earth does it say "voted"?

Comment: If it helps you pick, though I posted first, I only had that link because [Jon gave it to me in one of my old questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46750/clarification-in-faq-regarding-voting-reputation-and-accepted-answers/46758#46758)

Comment: I'll make it easy for you.

Comment: @Glorfindel It seems that the image host has changed the image behind the scenes, and so an archive link is necessary.

Comment: @sonic thanks, I'll adjust the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A delete action counts as a vote. In fact, most actions on the site count as votes. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/anatomy-of-a-data-dump/2678#2678) for a complete list.

So, trying to delete would be casting a vote, which you can't do since it is deleted.